CocoaPods Error: PBXGroup attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup. When tried to add WidgetExtension
I'm encountering an error while trying to run pod install for my Flutter project. The error message indicates that there is an issue with the PBXGroup initialization related to an unknown ISA PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup. Here are the details:
What did I do?
I attempted to run pod install in the ios directory of my Flutter project.
What did I expect to happen?
I expected CocoaPods to install the necessary dependencies without any errors.
What happened instead?
I received the following error:
RuntimeError - PBXGroup attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup from attributes:
{"isa"=>"PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup", 
"exceptions"=>["E97F44AD2CB644CA004719F6"], 
"explicitFileTypes"=>{}, "explicitFolders"=>[],
"path"=>"charge_liveactivity", 
"sourceTree"=>"<group>"}

Stack Trace:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:359:in rescue in object_with_uuid'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:349:in object_with_uuid'
...

Environment:
CocoaPods: 1.15.2
Ruby: ruby 3.3.5
Xcode: 16.0
macOS: 15.0.1
Podfile:
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  ...
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  ...
end

Additional Information:
I have tried updating CocoaPods and running pod repo update, but the issue persists. I also checked the project settings in Xcode, but I couldn't find any misconfigurations.

I was able to fix the issue by running updating cocaopods.
sudo gem update cocoapods

Then
sudo gem update xcodeproj


without sudo was enough for me!

In Xcode, right-click on the folder, select Convert to Group from the context menu, and then it can be used normally.
original answer - CocoaPods pod init Fails with “Unknown ISA PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup” Error on Xcode 16

This does not work for me

FYI, if you’re doing this in a new project that you just created in Xcode 16, you may get another error about the project file format. So, after you convert the folders to groups, you may also have to change the “project format” from Xcode 16.0, down to Xcode 15.3.

WATCH OUT: this will "fix" your build but it will break some iOS extensions. It broke App Intent's functionality for me and caused an internal error
Relie's solution below + flutter run upgrade did it for me.
This is happening because you have an old version of Flutter vs XCode 16 so updating everything is the ideal solution

@Rob we don't need to downgrade Xcode version. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79013326/16322682 please check out this.

@Jatin – Good to know. Back then (before Cocoapods v1.16), it was choking on Xcode 16 file formats in general. Looks like they’ve fixed that. That having been said, it looks like this “Convert to Group” might not be needed anymore, either.
